# Convert Video Dataset into 5D tensor and save it as .npy file

Tags: tensorflow, keras, video, conv-neural-network

I wanna convert a video dataset into 5d tensor and save as .npy file to give input to the CNN model

Could you please help with that if possible ??

Comment: What will be in the 5D tensor ? would it be something like (TIME, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS) ?

Comment: Batch size, height, width, number of frames, channels

Comment: Why do you have number of frames as a dim in the tensor ? Wouldn't the value of no of frames be the same for every frame in a given video ?

Comment: no. the number of frames is not the same for all videos

Comment: Use `tfds.features.Video` for videos, encoding frames individually on disk. For more details refer the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features/Video?version=nightly). Thanks!